# Is there a ReSharper-like code reformat and cleanup tool for Scala?

Tags: scala, refactoring, intellij-idea, resharper, automated-refactoring

I'd like to automatically clean-up and reformat a Scala code file the way I can do with ReSharper in Visual Studio for C#. Can I do this with IntelliJ Idea or another tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Code` | `Reformat code` action in IntelliJ IDEA, it works for Scala as well when you have Scala plug-in installed.

Comment: Reformat code will only reformat code, not clean it up like ReSharper ALT + ENTER in C# that magically re-writes code (often with LINQ) to be more concise and  usually more readable.  E.g. it will re-write a for loop removing elements from a list into 1 line using filter.  The scope for this kind of thing in scala is epic and a tool to do it would be epically awesome.

Comment: @samthebest There is also `Alt`+`Enter` in IDEA that can change code according to inspections/intentions.

Comment: True, but the yellow underline and auto-refactor idiom coverage in ReSharper for C# is vastly richer than for Scala. If a ReSharper for Scala was released I'd insist my company buy my team a license :)

Comment: @samthebest, it will not happen, I doubt there is anything better for Scala than IntelliJ IDEA right now. You can submit feature requests at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL.

Answer (score 7):

IntelliJ Idea has great scala support, via the [scala plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1347).

Reformating code can be accessed from the menu through: `Code` >> `Reformat Code`.

In fact, re-sharper is a product from JetBrains (authors of Idea)

Comment: I know. But I am asking about the particular function. I've managed to set up Idea for Scala (with Scala and SBT pligins for Idea and Idea plugin for SBT), but can't find how to use it to automatically clean-up and reformat a Scala code file (in VisualStudio with ReSharper this is a click away, in the code editor right-click menu).

Comment: Thanks, @CrazyCoder! That's what I was looking for (I'm just very new to Idea). Post this as an answer and I will accept it.